# JAVA Sorted string array by last char

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, sorting

How can I sorted string array by last char?
The last char is **number**.
I want to sort from highest number to lowest number

Thanks

```
int usa_celkem = usa + usa_p;
int cesko_celkem = cesko + cesko_p;
int kanada_celkem = kanada + kanada_p;
int slovensko_celkem = slovensko + slovensko_p;
int spanelsko_celkem = spanelsko + spanelsko_p;
int nizozemi_celkem = nizozemi + nizozemi_p;
int nemecko_celkem = nemecko + nemecko_p;

String[] pokus = {
                "USA" + Integer.toString(usa_celkem), 
                "CESKO" + Integer.toString(cesko_celkem),
                "KANADA" + Integer.toString(kanada_celkem),
                "SLOVENSKO" + Integer.toString(slovensko_celkem),
                "SPANELSKO" + Integer.toString(spanelsko_celkem),
                "NIZOZEMI" + Integer.toString(nizozemi_celkem),
                "NEMECKO" + Integer.toString(nemecko_celkem),
        };
```

Comment: You can write a custom comparator.

Comment: you override the Comparator and sort after the last chars, otherwise provide more clear data so that we can help you. What is usa_celkem and the rest, provide the full data like USA12 or what you want to sort.

Comment: I want to sort from highest number to lowest number

Answer (score 1):

Java 8

You can do this in a simple way. You just need to add the numbers to the string  and put them in the array, like this:

```
String[] pokus = {"USA10", "CESKO2", "KANADA32", "SLOVENSKO11", 
                      "SPANELSKO22", "NIZOZEMI3", "NEMECKO31"};

Arrays.sort(pokus,(a,b) -> Integer.compare(
                    Integer.parseInt(b.replaceAll("\\D+","")),
                    Integer.parseInt(a.replaceAll("\\D+",""))
));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pokus));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only digits are the digits at the end of the array members (there is no SPANEL2SKO12 i.e. 2 in the middle), you can use the code below

```
        String[] pokus = {
            "USA" + Integer.toString(10),
            "CESKO" + Integer.toString(2),
            "KANADA" + Integer.toString(32),
            "SLOVENSKO" + Integer.toString(11),
            "SPANELSKO" + Integer.toString(22),
            "NIZOZEMI" + Integer.toString(3),
            "NEMECKO" + Integer.toString(31),
    };

    Arrays.sort(pokus, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int a = Integer.valueOf(o1.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
            int b = Integer.valueOf(o2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
            return Integer.compare(b, a);
        }
    });

    for (String poku : pokus) {
        System.out.println(poku);
    }
```

Output:

```
KANADA32
NEMECKO31
SPANELSKO22
SLOVENSKO11
USA10
NIZOZEMI3
CESKO2
```

Comment: *"I want to sort from highest number to lowest number"* So, `return Integer.compare(b, a)`.

Answer (score -1):

As has been pointed out, you can write your own comparator for [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).
Assuming that you don't have nulls or empty Strings in your array, you can sort descending by last character using simple lambda expression as a Comparator like this:

```
Arrays.sort(pokus, (String a, String b) -> 
            Integer.compare(b.charAt(b.length() - 1), a.charAt(a.length() - 1)));
```

Where `pokus` is a name of the array.